# Digispark replacement Wire library

Tags: arduino, i2c

I have a dilemma:
I am trying to get a Digispark to read a BH1750 I2C light sensor and then send the readout via USB. Currently I'm using the DigiUSB library to send to the PC but the sketch is very big (can't implement any of the features I want, using 94% of the flash mem). At the moment it's just sending the value every 0.5 seconds, doing no calculations on it and I have to re-plug the device at boot. I know how to implement these features, it's just that there isn't enough space on the digispark, using both Wire and DigiUSB.
So in order to reduce the size I want to replace Digistump's big Wire library with SoftI2CMaster&SoftWire OR USIWire, both half the size.
I tried two BH1750 I2C libraries (both work fine with Digistump's Wire) but for all four combinations I get the following error:

```
In file included from C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_192160\Echo.ino:8:0:

C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SoftI2CMaster-master/SoftWire.h:101:10: error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual size_t SoftWire::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)'

   size_t write(const uint8_t *data, size_t quantity) {

          ^

In file included from C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/Stream.h:24:0,

                 from C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/TinyDebugSerial.h:31,

                 from C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/WProgram.h:18,

                 from C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/Arduino.h:4,

                 from sketch\Echo.ino.cpp:1:

C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/Print.h:75:18: error:   overriding 'virtual void Print::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)'

     virtual void write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size);

                  ^

exit status 1
```

I tried to figure out how to fix this "conflicting return type" error but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Google is often reliable in finding answers but not today.
Any help would be appreciated!